# C# date and time comparing

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table which contains a two column(`start_time` and `end_time`).I am getting the information of start and end time from the user and adding it to the table.Once the user enters the next start and end time I have to compare it with the database.

Suppose in table one row has start time as `2011-08-10 16:00:00` and end time is `2011-08-10 16:30:00`.
Suppose the user enter value `2011-08-10 16:05:00.000` (`start_time`) and `2011-08-10 16:25:00` (`end_time`) I am able to capture the by using

```
      String getConflictTimeInBetween = string.Format("select                           question_id,question_text from " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE + " where start_time<='{0}' and end_time>='{1}'", start_full, end_full);//question_text='DFS'"2011-06-23 14:55);//
                        com = new SqlCommand(getConflictTimeInBetween, myConnection);
                        dr = com.ExecuteReader();

                        if (dr.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                //Assign to your textbox here   
                                conflictQuestionIdAtBetween = dr["question_id"].ToString();
                                conflictQuestionTextAtBetween=dr["question_text"].ToString();
                            }
                        }
```

Here are some sample overlaps that I want to prevent

1. start_time from `2011-08-10 15:55:00` and end_time `2011-08-10 16:05:00` (five minutes overlap with already existing data)
2. start_time from `2011-08-10 16:25:00` and end_time `2011-08-10 17:00:00` (five minutes overlap with already existing data)
3. start_time from `2011-08-10 15:00:00` and end_time `2011-08-10 17:00:00` (30 minutes overlap with already existing data)

Can anyone help me how to solve these three issues.

Comment: This is trivial. Please provide us with what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: I think you're using the wrong term. Do you mean you want to prevent duplicate/overlapping data that happens in the same time range?

Comment: do you want to see overlap? do you want to get only times in between start and end? (in which case you will eventually have a timeframe of only 1 minute) exactly what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't want any overlapping to be have in between the start time and end time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to have the SQL part, here's the algorithm that finds the overlap in ticks between the input time and the row time.

```
    public long GetTimeOverlap(long inputStart, long inputEnd)
    {
        // I assume you can get the data yourself so heres only the algorithm.
        long rowStart = new DateTime().Ticks, rowEnd = new DateTime().Ticks;

        if (inputStart < rowStart)
            if (inputEnd >= rowEnd)
                // case 3
                return rowEnd - rowStart;
            else if (inputEnd > rowStart)
                // case 1
                return inputEnd - rowStart;
            // Input time is before row time.
            else return 0;
        else if (inputStart >= rowEnd)
            // Input time is after row time.
            return 0;
        else if (inputEnd >= rowEnd)
            // case 2
            return rowEnd - inputStart;
            // case 0
        else return inputEnd - inputStart;
    }
```

Comment: This will work if combined with my 3 queries and his query, but then he'd be getting much data back from the database and do the calculating on the client side. If I were him I'd use a better query to let the database do the math. Nonetheless, this is still an option.

Answer (score 1):

None of the 3 overlapping scenarios you mentioned will show up with the query you're using now. It's not clear from your post what you mean to achieve, but I can give you the queries that will show each scenario:

1) "select question_id,question_text from " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE + " where start_time>'{0}' and start_time<'{1}'", start_full, end_full);//question_text='DFS'"2011-06-23 14:55);

2) "select question_id,question_text from " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE + " where end_time>'{0}' and end_time<'{1}'", start_full, end_full);//question_text='DFS'"2011-06-23 14:55);

3) "select question_id,question_text from " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE + " where start_time>'{0}' and end_time<'{1}'", start_full, end_full);//question_text='DFS'"2011-06-23 14:55);

Comment: I know the above which i provided is not for these 3 issues.But how to handle these 3 issues.the  3 query u provided is all same.How to capture it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want to do to intersect the date ranges correctly is something like:

```
   String getConflictTimeInBetween = string.Format("select question_id,question_text from " + data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE + "where (start_time<='{0}' and end_time>='{0}') or ((start_time<='{1}' and end_time>='{1}')", start_full, end_full);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean in your question, however here is much better code:

```
String getConflictTimeInBetween = string.Format("select question_id,question_text from {0}  where start_time<=@start and end_time>=@end", data_variables.RES_TXT_STRING_QUESTION_TABLE);
using (com = new SqlCommand(getConflictTimeInBetween, myConnection))
{
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", Convert.ToDateTime(start_full));
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", Convert.ToDateTime(end_full));
    using (dr = com.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //Assign to your textbox here   
                conflictQuestionIdAtBetween = dr["question_id"].ToString();
                conflictQuestionTextAtBetween=dr["question_text"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's doing the same thing plus:

1. Prevent possible SQL Injection attacks by using Parameters instead of directly injecting the text.
2. Dispose the objects (command and reader) after using them to prevent connections from remaining open and crashing your database. This is done by the `using` blocks.